# Export many BusinessObjects 6.5 reports to excel at the same time by VBA from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I write the code which export bo 6.5 report to excel by settings from userform1 (login/password/variables parametrs). I need to refresh 100 reports from the folder and export it to excel. First report can refresh 1hour, second 10 min, third 3 hour and etc. So there is the code when refresh report 1 - export it to excel - and start refresh report 2. Problem is that report 2 dont refreshing until report 1 not ready. Without vba i can open application BO 6.5 open report 1 and start refresh it, then open second process of application BO 6.5 and open and refresh report 2. If i want to refresh 100 reports at the same time - it will be 100 bo 6.5 process. So with refresh reports by different process its huge time economy.

My code for refresh report 1 and after finish refresh report 2. How to make that report 2 start refreshing with no waiting when report 1 finish ?

```
Sub boreport(ByVal xlogin As String, ByVal xpassword As String, ByVal xdate1 As String, ByVal xdate2 As String, ByVal xdatetovar As String)
Dim lMsgFilter As Long
CoRegisterMessageFilter 0&, lMsgFilter
Dim BOApp As busobj.Application
Set BOApp = New busobj.Application
Dim xname As String
BOApp.LoginAs xlogin, xpassword, False, "bomain6"
BOApp.Visible = False


Set docBO = BOApp.Documents.Open("C:\rep\report1.rep")
xname = BOApp.ActiveDocument.Name
x = docBO.Variables.Count
docBO.Variables.Item("1. Дата начала периода").Value = xdate1
docBO.Variables.Item("2. Дата окончания периода").Value = xdate2
docBO.Variables.Item("3. Дата информации о товаре").Value = xdatetovar
BOApp.Interactive = False
docBO.Refresh
BOApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\repxl\" & xname & ".xls")
BOApp.ActiveDocument.Save

Set docBO = BOApp.Documents.Open("C:\rep\report2.rep")
xname = BOApp.ActiveDocument.Name
x = docBO.Variables.Count
docBO.Variables.Item("1. Дата начала периода").Value = xdate1
docBO.Variables.Item("2. Дата окончания периода").Value = xdate2
docBO.Variables.Item("3. Дата информации о товаре").Value = xdatetovar
BOApp.Interactive = False
docBO.Refresh
BOApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\repxl\" & xname & ".xls")
BOApp.ActiveDocument.Save
BOApp.Interactive = True
BOApp.Visible = True

BOApp.Quit
MsgBox ("ready" & x)
CoRegisterMessageFilter lMsgFilter, lMsgFilter
End Sub
```

i trying make report refresh by for next loop, but there is same result - for i = 1 (report1 name) - report1 start refreshing and report 2 (i = 2) waiting report1.